# Nginx cant serve files with special symbols in them?

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, http-status-code-404

So in browser i request a file that i know it exists

3a1c2aa4d488ae4d?s=40?f=78

but it gives me a 404 error and in log says that it couldn't find file named 3a1c2aa4d488ae4d.
For some reason it cuts the part of the filename after ? and tries to open that file instead.

I would understand the problem in windows but this is Centos.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `?` will be considered as parameters, as the request will be considered as HTML [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). You need to [encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the special symbols so that they are treated as characters and not command parts.

Better yet, use sensible file names.